# JavaScript: не понимаю почему 11 на выходе?

Tags: javascript

```js
var x = 1;
for (; x < 6; x += 2) {
  x = x * x;
}
document.write(x);
```

Comment: Что удивляет? Поставь дополнительно вывод x внутри цикла перед и после умножения - и всё увидишь...

Answer (score 4):

[Синтаксис](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

`for ([инициализация]; [условие]; [финальное выражение]) выражение`

> ***финальное выражение***
>
> Выражение, выполняющееся в конце интерации цикла. Происходит до
>   следующего выполнения условия. Обычно используется для обновления или
>   увеличения переменной счётчика.

т.е. когда `x = 3 * 3` сначала отрабатывает инкремент (**до
следующего выполнения условия, Карл**) `x += 2`, а уже потом проверка условия `x < 6`

Answer (score 2):

Цикл проходит у вас 2 раза) пройдемся по шагам

1 итерация x = 1; x = 1 * 1; // x = 1

2 итерация x = 1 + 2; 
x = 3 * 3; x = 9

3 итерация x = 9 + 2; x = 11; 11 < 6 (выходим из цикла)

Comment: а в первом обороте x+= 2 не выполняется? @lazyproger

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, При первой итерации `x` - исходный. Автор сообщения делает увеличение в начале следующей итерации